# How can I find the value of the coefficients of an inverse exponential graph?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

If I have a set of discrete data points and I want to find the line of best fit of the form $$y=Ae^{-Bx}$$

then I can do the following:
$$\ln(y)=-Bx+\ln(A)$$

Therefore, if I plot $(x,\ln(y)$), the gradient is the $-B$ coefficient of my line of best fit and my $y$-intercept is $\ln(A)$ of my line of best fit.

**Note**: The above method, finds the values of the coefficient of my line of best fit using all data points, and not just choosing two and solving a set of equations.

---

Now, if I have a set of data points and I want to fit a function of the following form:
$$y=A(e^{-Bx}-1)+C$$

how can I find the value of the coefficients? The method above would not work for this scenario. Instead how could I identify the value of the coefficients $A, B$ and $C$?

**Note**: ${A,B,C \in \mathbb R }$ and $x$ and $y$ can be either positive or negative.

Comment: Is the constant $ B $ positive ?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Not necessarily, $B$ can also be negative. I have also amended the question

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are already aware that by doing a linear regression on $\log y$ you are minimizing
the **relative error** of $y$ , i.e. $\Delta y/y$ and not just $\Delta y$.

That said, in linear regression the line is always passing through the barycenter of the cloud of points $\left( {\overline x ,\,\overline y } \right)$.

So I would suggest that you operate in this way
$$
\eqalign{
  & y = A\left( {e^{\, - Bx}  - 1} \right) + C = Ae^{\, - Bx}  + D  \cr 
  & \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & \left( {y - \bar y} \right)
 = \left( {Ae^{\, - B\,\bar x} } \right)e^{\, - B\left( {x - \bar x} \right)}  + \left( {D - \bar y} \right)  \cr 
  & \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  D - \bar y \hfill \cr 
  \Delta y = A'e^{\, - B\Delta x}  \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Performing a linear best fit to the log of the data works if you assume that the measurements' noise are Gaussian distributed *after* taking the log. While there may be some trick to reduce the second case to a linear fit, it is probably better to assume that the noise is Gaussian in the original form and perform a non linear regression, based on a maximum likelihood estimation.